# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I know this problem has been posted but all seemed to be posted in java code.  I'm just trying to implement a small example recyclerView.  Not sure what I'm doing incorrect, any insight would be great, TIA.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.wildcardev.androidtest1

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.adapters.RecyclerAdapter
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.models.TestDataObj

fun addDataToList(arrayList:ArrayList<TestDataObj>): ArrayList<TestDataObj>{
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("tes1", "test2", "test3"))
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("test2", "testt2", "testt2"))
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("tes12", "test22", "test32"))
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("tes13", "test23", "test33"))
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("tes14", "test24", "test34"))
    arrayList.add(TestDataObj("tes15", "test25", "test35"))
    return arrayList
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
     val testList: ArrayList<TestDataObj> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val list = addDataToList(testList)
        Log.d("TEST1","$list")
        Log.d("TEST1","${binding.recyclerView}")

        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(list)
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }

}
```

TestDataObj.kt
package com.wildcardev.androidtest1.models

```
data class TestDataObj(
   val title: String,
   val description: String,
   val date: String
)
```

RecyclerAdapter.kt
package com.wildcardev.androidtest1.adapters

```
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.R
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.models.TestDataObj

class RecyclerViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    var title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title)
    var description: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.description)
    var date: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.date)
}

class RecyclerAdapter(private var list: ArrayList<TestDataObj>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        Log.d("onCreateView", "INHOLDERcreate")
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "INBINDfunc")
        val item = list[position]

        holder.title.text = item.title
        holder.description.text = item.description
        holder.date.text = item.date
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("COUNT",".getItemCountcalled")
        return list.size
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Kotlin/Java. You need to call `setContentView()` with `binding.root` instead of `R.layout.activity_main`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities

Comment: good catch, still getting that error.  I also modified to "TextView?" in the class RecyclerViewHolder

Comment: Well, it's not really an error, but if you're still getting it, then you have some other `RecyclerView` that's getting laid out without an `Adapter` attached, but there's not enough information here for us to be able to tell you anything more specific.

Comment: Thanks, thought there may be something glaringly wrong in the code.  Thanks for pointing out using "binding.root"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue.  When using viewBinding/dataBinding, you need to pass dataBinding to the viewHolder.  Unfortunately I did not get this as I was just following tutorials that are using synthetic imports.  So I changed my Adapter code to the following

RecyclerAdapter.kt

```
    package com.wildcardev.androidtest1.adapters

import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.models.TestDataObj
import com.wildcardev.androidtest1.databinding.ListItemBinding

class RecyclerViewHolder(viewDataBinding: ListItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(viewDataBinding.root){
    var title: TextView? = viewDataBinding.title
    var description: TextView? = viewDataBinding.description
    var date: TextView? = viewDataBinding.date
}

class RecyclerAdapter(private var list: ArrayList<TestDataObj>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        Log.d("onCreateView", "INHOLDERcreate")
        val binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("ADAPTER", "INBINDfunc $holder")
        val item = list[position]

        holder.title?.text = item.title
        holder.description?.text = item.description
        holder.date?.text = item.date
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("COUNT",".getItemCountcalled ${list.size}")
        return list.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)